# Cutoff frequency of a second order low pass RLC circuit

Tags: passive-networks, low-pass, passive-filter

L = 25 mH, R =1 kOhm, C = 10nF and Vs(t)=sin(wt)V, freq = 500 Hz
I am trying to calculate the cutoff frequency of a second order low pass RLC circuit 
[image: Second-order low pass RLC]
I don't know if I can still apply the formula of simple RC circuits which is: $$f_{c}=\dfrac{1}{2\cdot \pi\cdot RC}$$
Is there another formula?

Comment: Your RC formula is only for a first order RC circuits. It misses the inductor L that also must be considered. So you have to find a formula for the second order circuit.

Comment: Just some minor nitpicking: did you mean **L**=25mH and **C**=10nF, by any chance? Or L=10nH and C=25mF? Most probably the 1st, but for clarification.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen It is C=10nF and L=25mH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there another formula?

There is the correct formula (rather than your incorrect formula): -

$$F_C = \dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$

This is the natural resonant frequency for a 2nd order low pass filter and is not necessarily the 3dB cut-off frequency because the 2nd order type filter has the ability to produce a peak in the frequency response. Here's a picture based on your component values: -

[image]

Picture from [this interactive filter website](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html#RLC_low_pass_filter_type_2) and notice that at the natural resonant frequency (10.7 kHz) the attenuation is 3.979 dB. If you use the cursor you can find the 3 dB point to be about 8.92 kHz.

Answer (score 3):

The best is to derive your expression yourself and using the [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371) or fast analytical circuits techniques it is a child's play. The principle is easy: determine the resistance offered by the energy-storing elements when they are temporarily disconnected from the circuit. This is done when the excitation (\$V_{in}\$) is reduced to 0 V or replaced by a short circuit:

[image]

Simply "look" through the component's connections and write what resistance do you "see". In this mode, the second energy-storing element is set in its dc state (a short for an inductor and an open circuit for a capacitor). For the first time constant involving \$L_1\$, it is \$R_1\$ so the time constant is \$\tau_1=\frac{L_1}{R_1}\$. For the second time constant involving \$C_2\$ the resistance is 0 ohms hence \$\tau_2=0\$. For the second-order time constant, set \$L_1\$ in its high frequency state and look at the resistance offered by \$C_2\$: \$\tau_{12}=C_2R_1\$. That is all we need to do, no equations no algebra. The complete transfer function can be written as:

\$H(s)=\frac{1}{1+s(\tau_1+\tau_2)+s^2\tau_1\tau_{12}}=\frac{1}{1+s\frac{L_1}{R_1}+s^2L_1C_2}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_0Q}+\frac{s^2}{\omega_0^2}}\$ in which \$\omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L_1C_2}}\$ and \$Q=R_1\sqrt\frac{C_2}{L_1}\$

A quick Mathcad sheet to test this formula, and you're done:

[image]

No algebra, just inspection and we have determined this 2nd-order transfer function is a few tens of seconds using the FACTs.

**Edit**

Now the question was also about the -3dB-cutoff frequency. How do we obtain it from the transfer function? Simply derive the magnitude expression from the Laplace transfer function (replace \$s\$ by \$j\omega\$) by collecting real and imaginary parts:

\$|H(\omega)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-C_2L_1\omega^2)^2+(\frac{L_1} {R_1}\omega)^2}}\$

Then solve \$\omega\$ satisfying the equality \$|H(\omega)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$.

Using Mathcad to do that, you find 8.894 kHz as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Verbal Kint_is the shown magnitude response a general example or do you think it would be the specific result for the given circuit?

Comment: There is a mistake in one of your formulas - you say \$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{L_1C_1}\$ and this is incorrect. Also, wouldn't it make more sense to actually solve for the values in the question as I have?

Comment: Hello Andy, oops, thanks for pointing this out, the square root disappeared from the text in this rainy afternoon : ) The sheet is also updated with values from the example. Merci.

Comment: Guten abend LvW, the shown magnitude is that of a second-order network without roots in the numerator (zeroes). Add a small resistance \$r_C\$ in series with \$C_2\$ and a zero will appear in the response, bringing the phase up in high frequencies. Was it the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @VerbalKint yeah but it took 2 hours not the few tens of seconds you said LOL. I suppose if you looked at the time difference between the OP asking his question and me answering it that was 2 hours and 2 minutes so, not much difference hehe.

Comment: Well, it took me 30 s to derive the expression, probably 15 mn to draw the sketch and build the correct Mathcad sheet and that's about it. It's time for a glass of wine actually! Cheers.

Comment: @VerbalKint_OK, I see that you have corrected your results because there were some rrors in your answer (poleQ was above "3" and the corresponding peak in the frequency respoonse was wrong). More than that, the questioner is looking for the 3dB-cut-off frequency.

Comment: @LvW, there was no error in the Mathcad sheet, I originally selected component values that gave a high \$Q\$ and a peaky response. I just put the values from the example and updated the sheet. For the -3-dB response, I'll try to post a new sheet tonight.